# Attempting to open nonexistent file causes seg fault?

Tags: segmentation-fault, fopen

I have a program that is supposed to mimic certain shell commands.  One of these commands that I am supposed to create is cat, but I am having a problem with it.  When I run it on a file that exists, it works, but when I attempt to run it on a file that doesn't exist, I get a segmentation fault.  Even though I thought I've been told that fopen() can be used to check for a file's existence without causing a segmentation fault.  The code for the cat portion of the code is below (there are some variables that were declared earlier, like token, but I've included some comments to explain what they are, however I'm pretty certain the problem has nothing to do with those variables.)

```
if(strncmp(token, "cat", 3) == 0){
            FILE* in;
            char tLine[500];
            char f;
            //Copy the entire line of user input from earlier into a temporary char array
            strcpy(tLine, inputLine);
            /*Advance the char array that contains the original line of input 
            split by spaces to the first argument*/
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            //For storing the number of arguments
            int count = 0;
            //Determine number of arguments
            while(token != NULL){
                count++;
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }
            strcpy(tLine, inputLine);
            token = strtok(tLine, " ");
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            if(count < 1){
                printf("%s", "Please enter at least one argument");
            }
            else if (count > 1){
                printf("%s", "Please only enter one argument");
            }
            //If there is only one argument, attempt to open the file and read its contents.
            else{
                in = fopen(token, "r");
                if(in){
                    f = fgetc(in);
                    while(f != EOF){
                        printf("%c", f);
                        f = fgetc(in);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    printf("%s", "Could not open file.");
                }
                fclose(in);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You never check the return value of fopen.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that part (I had changed it to the access function earlier because I thought it might not crash it).  It still has the same problem.

Comment: Don't `fclose` if `fopen` failed.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem.

Comment: Eyeballing the causes of segfault is not always possible. If you post a buildable code with test cases, you will be more likely get faster and better response.